# TYPO3 Extbase Querybuilder add 'AND 1<>1' at the end of constraints

Tags: sql, typo3, query-builder, extbase

I've create a M:N relation in TYPO3 Extbase. 
With following code I've added the contraints to QueryBuilder.

```
foreach ($selectedFeatures as $value) {
            $constraints[] = $query->contains('features', $value);
    }
$query->matching(
                $query->logicalAnd(
                        $constraints
                        )
                );
```

It works fine till 4 Features. After this the QueryBuilder add at the end of the constraints 'AND 1<>1'.
And this is the reason why I've got no result.

Does anybody know what this could be? Each item in '$selectedFeatures' are objects from 'Feature' model. That's I've checked and this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in [`Typo3DbQueryParser`](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/_typo3_db_query_parser_8php_source.html#l00395) when the second operand is `null`. So you‘ll have to find out why and under which circumstances `$value`, i.e. one of your `$selectedFeatures`, happens to be `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this not possible. I've write each item from $selectedFeatures in a log file to check the value and no one is null. Additional I've added an if condition which check the value !is_null($value).

Comment: Ah, you checked that. Are there other constraints in your query? `$query->in()` can produce `1<>1`, too. It must be one of both, it‘s the only occurrence of `<>` operator in the whole of extbase. And we don‘t need to grep for `'<' . '>'`, do we?

Comment: No, no more constraints in this query. This problem occurs as I deleted one feature. But this feature not exist in the whole project anymore. Before I deleted this one, the query works fine.

Comment: So you‘re suffering from a "ghost" feature :-(. Where are your features defined? Do they come from flexform?

Comment: A user choose the features in a frontend form. After submit, I've mapped the entries with the Feature Model.